# Simple VM that allows booting from folder or disk

Tags: operating-system, virtual-machine, bootloader

I was wondering if there was a very simple and free virtual machine that would allow you to boot from a folder or disk image that couldn't damage my hard disk. I am using a MacBook and am looking into operating system programming. I found [a tutorial on the internet that looked promising](http://www.viralpatel.net/taj/tutorial/hello_world_bootloader.php). I want to try this but using a VM instead of actually booting from a disk. If I made a folder or disk image containing the `boot.bin` file and wanted to try the OS I made (while booting from a folder or disk image, not a disk), is there a VM that would let me do it? I have no previous experience with virtual machines. I also want to be sure my hard disk would not be damaged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can make a cdfs .ISO, any VM technology on the market today could do what you ask.  VirtualBox, KVM, Xen, VMware, VMware Fusion (on the macbook), etc.  Not sure if Parallels can work for you, though.

VMware's products can also boot from floppy images, which are simply binary blobs (for the most part).

On the Mac I think you're limited to VMware Fusion (maybe Parallels), but on Linux you have so many options.

Answer (score 1):

[virtualbox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) (formerly from Sun, now from Oracle) is probably the most powerful VM that you can run on all of Windows, Macs and Linux (OpenSolaris too of course;-) and is at the same time open source (and, of course, also free as in free beer).  Whether it supports your new OS is not entirely certain (since it's oriented to supporting a specific list of "guest OS"s and of course your new one isn't there), but, what with it being free, it's surely worth giving it a try.